# Dependency repository has been deleted but still exists in Ubuntu Server running Django app

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, setup.py

I have a small issue with our servers and the dependency that has been installed on one of them. While I had once run a `python setup.py develop` to install a dependency from a github repository and then removed that file I am now trying to figure out if I could repack this dependency. The github account that I cloned from has been deleted and so I am no longer able to create similar intances/servers (unless I clone, which I would like to avoid).

Comment: _"removed that file"_ - which file did you remove?

Comment: So when I cloned the repository with the directory, I entered the directory then installed the dependency followed by removing the directory upon finishing.